# Core Data - fetchBatchSize ignored

Tags: ios, core-data

I am setting up a NSFetchedResultsController, set a batch size on the request and perform the fetch.

Based on the performance, memory usage, logging (whenever attribute of the entity is accessed), and SQL logging (no mention of limits in the SQL query), it clearly appears that fetchBatchSize is ignored, and that all my objects are fetched).

What could be the causes for that setting to be ignored?

```
NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest new];
NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:context];
[request setEntity:entity];
[request setSortDescriptors:[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"dateCreated" ascending:NO]];
[request setFetchBatchSize:50];

self.fetchController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc]
                        initWithFetchRequest:request
                        managedObjectContext:context
                        sectionNameKeyPath:nil
                        cacheName:nil];
NSError *error;
[self.fetchController performFetch:&error];
```

Note that if I set a breakpoint just before the fetch, the request is indeed set with a batch size limit of 50; but SQL logging has no mention of it.

Comment: This is apparently a known bug as confirmed by a member of the Core Data team in [a discussion on Apple's developer forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1083395#1083395). You should probably file your own bug about it, since extra reports drive priorities for fixing bugs.

Comment: Setting cacheName helped for iOS 9 but still has problem with iOS 10