# Solution to NSFetchResultsController memory handling

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nsfetchrequest

Recently I was working on an application that allowed the ability to create and browse through a large quantity of data at a time.
In this application, it is possible to have 2,000+ objects that can be viewed in a `collectionView` from a `NSFetchedResultsController` at a single point in time.

When testing this scenario, it was soon discovered and verified that `NSFetchedResultsController` does not optimally page `NSManagedObject`s in and out of memory when accessing batched indexes.

As indexes are accessed from the `NSFetchedResultsController` and more `NSManagedObject`s are loaded, it seemed that `NSFetchedResultsController` would retain the previously loaded `NSManagedObject`s in memory rather page them in and out of memory per accessed indexes set using the `fetchBatchSize` set in the `fetchRequest`. To explain this further, if the `fetchBatchSize` is set to 45, and index 1,000 is now loaded, the `NSFetchedResultsController` seems to hold onto the memory for everything prior to index 1,000 that has been loaded via index access rather faulted.

If `managedObjectContext.reset()` is called on the parent context, the memory is properly released until the objects are loaded again via index access. The `fetchBatchSize` seems to only prevent all of the data from being loaded at once. When indexes are access, the `NSFetchedResultsController` seems to load the new batch, while holding onto the previously loaded batches.

My current contemplations are leading me to create my own paging where I'll have multiple `fetchResultsControllers` with `fetchBatchSize`s and `fetchLimit`s... which seems far more complicated then it should be. This will create a manual way of paging the data in out out of memory allowing proper memory management.

My question is if there’s a better way to approach this? I essentially would like to page infinite objects similar to Apple's Photos application (which their performance blows my mind), while using CoreData.

Note: There have been plenty of posts on this exact issue noting that people have had to work out manual solutions to improve memory management (Example: [link#1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27515373/core-data-fetchbatchsize-ignored), [link#2](https://github.com/Simperium/simperium-ios/issues/425)). I’m not looking for answers that note “did you forget this” or “you probably did this wrong”. I can verify without doubt, I am properly using the APIs as documented. I’m looking for a solution that helps manage the memory of `NSFetchedResultsController` better. Setting `fetchBatchSize` is a temporary solution until the user has loaded a high number of indexes that leads to a memory warning being fired off and me resetting the `managedObjectContext`. And before noted, yes I've testing with and without `NSFetchedResultsController` cache being set and reset accordingly.... if anything I've found separate issues with the cache itself and it doesn't really help with the problem at hand what-so-ever.

Comment: `fetchBatch`? Did you mean `fetchBatchSize`?

Comment: Yes, I didn't copy/paste the exact function names and just breezed through the general idea/concepts

Comment: Have you considered manual faulting unneeded objects with 
`refreshObject:object mergeChanges:NO`?

Comment: Yes, I started going down this route and realized it was more annoying than anything. I started hitting major issues when trying to fault and un fault objects appropriately. (and just as a heads up my stack is privateContext -> mainContext -> privateContext Spawns). I would create an in memory object with a copy of the core data variables, pass that variable back, and if something changed and the fetch results controller delegates where called, that's where I hit major issues.

Comment: Nested contexts are known to have bugs, such as not obeying `fetchBatchSize` setting. Have you tried this on a single main context, directly connected to PSC? I think it's possible that you have a 1000 objects materialized per every context, and it's possible that they will not be faulted if they have relationships to other materialized objects.

Comment: I found a temporary work around for the time being in setting up smaller data structures. Unfortunately, this is a fairly complex application that requires a lot of background processing states meaning it relies heavily on background contexts, so I'm not able to test one a single main context to see if the issue persists. I was able to alleviate the issue by removing the only data blob being saved to the tables, just a 5 - 20kb blob that now loads from disk. Apparently, that corrected the memory issue, and now the application is properly paging memory. The whole thing just mind boggled me.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you are not using the fetched results controller or Core Data correctly. I have had scenarios with 150.000 records and more powered by a fetched results controller with no memory (or performance) problems.

Some details about the setup that worked without quirks:

- context is of course main thread context
- `fetchBatchSize` is not set
- (optional) use a uniquely named cache (last argument in fetched results controller init)

  - you will have to reset the cache when reloading this controller

Also make sure that you are not storing huge images or other `BLOB`s directly in Core Data - that will definitely degrade performance and result in memory management problems. If you need to display images, lazy-load them.

Comment: Nope, all of this I have a full understanding of and as mentioned in the original question, all of this is applied and applied properly. The issue I'm seeing is once again memory being held onto.

Comment: No it doesn't. I clearly state I set the fetchBatchSize and as it pulls in data in batches, it seems to not fault data, it just loads more.

Comment: It shows that you have used it, while I suggest that you don't.

Comment: Right, which I clearly state I am using it and it's set as you've noted. I explicitly mentioned that I am using it to veer away from filler answers similar to the IT joke of "have you turned it off and on again" in hopes of a valuable answer to my issue. There are many forums and questions regarding this exact issue when dealing with large amounts of data in an enterprise environment, so it's no secret that this is the issue at hand (which I've verified). I'm not looking for blunt repetitive simple answers, rather I'm looking for decent viable solutions.

Comment: The question is not "what Am I doing wrong ". The question is, I've used all the recommended methods properly and found a problem with the API, what's the best way to work around this issue.